# Reading the Forwarded Events from the Event Viewer

Tags: c#, event-viewer

I want the parse throw the Forwarded Events in the Event Viewer to get an overview about the last 12 hours.
This is not a problem when using the application or system log. But when I try the same with the Forwarded Events log it throws an error.

Error Message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The event log 'ForwardedEvents' on computer '.' does not exist
```

The way I get the Logs at the moment:

```
EventLog systemLog = new EventLog("System");
EventLog forwardedLog = new EventLog("ForwardedEvents");
```

So I tried changing the ForwardedEvents to "system\forwardedevents", "Forwarded Events" but this also did not work.

I noticed that if I' using the following the the Forwarded Events don't show up.

```cs
EventLog.GetEventLogs()
```

Is there any other way to read the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [EventLogReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Try with the following:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("ForwardedEvents", PathType.LogName);

            try
            {
                EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);

                for (EventRecord eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent(); eventdetail != null; eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(eventdetail.FormatDescription());
                }
            }
            catch (EventLogNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error while reading the event logs");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I don't have any forwarded event but it does not fail.